# MultiThreading Synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a synchronized method , I created two thread object when I execute the the program. the thread output is not determined. Can any body check and let me know what is wrong with this implementation

```
package com.karthi.threads;

public class ThreadSyncDemo  extends Thread{


    String name;

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        wish();
    }

    public synchronized void wish(){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.println("Good morning");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print(name);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ThreadSyncDemo th = new ThreadSyncDemo();
        th.name="Test";
        th.start();
        ThreadSyncDemo th1 = new ThreadSyncDemo();
        th1.name="Test1";
        th1.start();

    }

}
```

output:

Good morning
Good morning
Test1Good morning
TestGood morning
Test1Good morning
TestGood morning
Test1TestGood morning
Good morning
Test1TestGood morning
Good morning
TestTest1

Expected output:

Good morning
TestGood morning
TestGood morning
TestGood morning
TestGood morning
TestGood morning
Test1Good morning
Test1Good morning
Test1Good morning
Test1Good morning
Test1

Comment: It's because you have two **different** objects with separate locks.  Each thread sees its own lock and can't see the other.  In an example like this if you want one common lock you might use a static member: `public static synchronized void wish()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take class level lock instead of object level:

```java
synchronized (ThreadSyncDemo.class)
{
   //lock at class level
}

{
public class ThreadSyncDemo extends Thread{
    String name;

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        wish();
    }

    public synchronized void wish(){
        synchronized(ThreadSyncDemo.class) {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                System.out.println("Good morning");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.print(name);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ThreadSyncDemo th = new ThreadSyncDemo();
        th.name="Test";
        th.start();
        ThreadSyncDemo th1 = new ThreadSyncDemo();
        th1.name="Test1";
        th1.start();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are locking at the object level.

You have two objects `th` and `th1`, they both have separate locks.

What you want is to lock at the class level.

One option is to lock at the class it self.

```
synchronized (ThreadSyncDemo.class)
{
   //lock at class level
}
```

Another is to have an explicit lock in the class like this

`private final static Object lock = new Object();`

And then synchronize on it

```
synchronized (lock)
{

}
```

The other method is to use `static` keyword on the synchronized method or block, because static methods are one per class this locks at the class level. It's not well suited here because of the way you have written this class (In a thread it self).

Answer (score 0):

You are using two objects. Instead you can create two threads of the same object so that each thread can see other threads lock.